# Data corruption on loading and save http image in java

Tags: java, image, http

I want to download a http url image http://68.142.23.19:8080/tmp/snap1.jpg . The Java code I use is:

```
public static void downloadFile(){
    System.out.println("Comenzando");
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(
                new URL("http://68.142.23.19:8080/tmp/snap1.jpg").openStream(), 
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\pruebas\\snap1.jpg")
            );
        System.out.println("Generada");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the image downloads but with a distortion in the footer:

[image: photo]

in a web browser navigator thought Internet this problem also occurred.

Being connected by LAN directly to the source of the image, the problem does not occur.

Please help me to understand and fix this issue.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you visit that URL in your browser?

Comment: Did you try other `IOUtils.copy` methods? (E.g.: one that contains the encoding Charset)

Comment: This image also appears corrupted viewing on a browser which means it's a problem with the source, not your code